# The Get Functions of ERC1820 (added in genesis file) not working correctly on Quorum

Tags: quorum, bytecode, genesis, erc-777, erc1820

Because I cannot deploy the magic ERC1820 directly to my private Quorum Network, I must add it to the genesis file like this:

```
  "0x1820a4b7618bde71dce8cdc73aab6c95905fad24": {
    "balance": "0x100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "code": "0x6080604052...6c0029"
  }
```

The code comes from Etherscan: https://etherscan.io/address/0x1820a4b7618bde71dce8cdc73aab6c95905fad24#code

The chain starts successfully. After that I open remix, connect it to my RPC-node and attach the address `0x1820a4B7618BdE71Dce8cdc73aAB6C95905faD24` to the IERC1820 interface.

The Problem is when I call "Get" (view) functions from remix or another contract they don't work and they try to return "0x60806...." as byte32. "Set" functions seem to work (no revert or error), but I cannot verify it because the "Get" functions are not working

[image]

I'm using this to start my Quorum Network https://consensys.net/docs/goquorum/en/latest/tutorials/quorum-dev-quickstart/

Version: quorum:22.4.3
and `raft` as GOQUORUM_CONS_ALGO in the .env file

the genesis block is simple:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Problem was the used [byte code](https://etherscan.io/address/0x1820a4b7618bde71dce8cdc73aab6c95905fad24#code) from mainnet.

I was able to solve this by deploying the [ERC1820 contract](https://github.com/0xjac/ERC1820/blob/master/contracts/ERC1820Registry.sol) "again" using remix to my Quorum network (The address will be different to 0x1820...) and then using the JSON-RPC and the new address I got the code of the deployed contract.

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8545' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "method": "eth_getCode",
    "params": [
        "0xBca0fDc68d9b21b5bfB16D784389807017B2bbbc",
        "latest"
    ],
    "id": 1
}'
```

After that, I copied the returned code from the response, modified the genesis file again with the new code (also added `"berlinBlock":0`), removed&deleted the containers, and started them again from scratch with the modified genesis file.